# Picking numbers from a list with Gaussian distribution (programming implementation)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, programming

If we have values:

$x \in [0, 100]$

I would like to implement a method, where the bigger the value, the less likely it is that it will be picked. (something like a Gaussian curve, but with maximum at the start of the list)

My first idea would be, to make an ordered list:

$\{0,0,...,0,1,1,...1,....,98,98,98,99,99,100\}$

Where the lower the element is, the more duplicates it has.
Then I would take the elements out of the list by randomly generating an integer between $0$ and $length(list)$, to pick the element out of the list by it's index. So the lower the number, higher the probability that it will be picked from the list.

However this is a very DIY approach to a problem like that. Is there a more sophisticated mathematical implementation approach to get (something like a Gaussian curve having it's maximum at the start of the list).

(I am programming in Java)

If my initial idea was good, then how many duplicates of each element should I make, to match the Gaussian curve.

EDIT:

The description of the application that I want is that the lower the number, the more probability there is that it will be picked from the list. However I am open to ideas on how to do that more sophistically.

Comment: The "Gaussian curve" does not match your description.  Setting aside the continuous nature of the Gaussian distribution and the discrete nature of your distribution, the Gaussian curve is known for its symmetry and central peak while your distribution peaks at the left end.  Perhaps you should back up and explain the application you have in mind so Readers can suggest a more fitting distribution.

Comment: @hardmath I have added an edit to the question. It is quite simple, the first thing that got to my mind was the Gaussian curve with discrete points along it's curve. However I am open to other ideas.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), which is discrete and can be parameterized to have a peak at the low end of outcomes.  However the likelihood of outcomes toward the other end diminish exponentially, which might be such low probabilities that it doesn't suit your purpose.  But you could feel that you had implemented a sophisticated approach.

Comment: If you don’t particularly care about the actual distribution, select $U$ and $V$ from $U(0,1)$ and set $Z= 101\,\vert U-V\vert$. Take the integer part.

Comment: @Aruralreader Can you explain a little bit more what you had in mind ?

Comment: My mistake, I missed the Gaussian requirement, so my comment doesn’t apply.

Comment: @Aruralreader It doesn't have to  necessarily be Gaussian. It's just that the probability of a higher number is way smaller than that of a lower number

Comment: $\vert U - V\vert$ has a triangular density on $[0, 1]$, max at $0$ and decreasing to zero at $1$. That'll focus your draws in the way you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be to

- generate a (pseudo-)random number $U$ uniformly on $(0,1)$
- take some suitable function $f:(0,1) \to (0,1)$
- multiply $f(U)$ by $101$ and round down: i.e. $\lfloor 101 f(U)\rfloor$

So it is a matter of a suitable function, a quantile or inverse CDF.

One possibility is $f(u)=1-\sqrt{1-u}$ which would give you something close to a triangular distribution with its peak at $0$.  Other functions will produce different distributions

Answer (score 1):

Your initial idea was on the right track, but let me refine it a bit (and perhaps expand what @Henry was referring to):

- Make a $n\times 2$ table with the first column being the value you
  want to extract $v_i$, and the second column its *weight*, $w_i$ ,
  i.e. the relative amount of times you want to draw this.
- Now draw a uniform (float) random number $u$, between $0$ and
  $W=\sum_1^n w_i$.
- To select the value $v$, find the first $i^*$ so       that $\sum _1
     ^{i^*} w_j > u$.
- Return $v_{i^*}$.

You can see that the number of times the random number $u$ will produce $i$ is proportional to $w_i$, as expected.

The issue now becomes how to choose a "good" weight. To do this, consider the plot of $v$ versus $w$, Since $v$ are given, you can choose $w$ to be whatever the problem demands, for example, a Gaussian would be, $w \sim e^{-v^2 \over 2\sigma}$ for some standard deviation $\sigma$.